# How to set flavour dependency on another flavour in gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have created a flavor to run a different espresso test. However, I have few dependency on androidTestCompile and I don't want to copy and paste all the dependancy as below. Is there a way I can create dependency on two different flavour?

```
productFlavors {
   androidTestFlavor {

   }
}

dependencies {
   androidTestCompile 'blah1'
   androidTestCompile 'blah2'
   androidTestCompile 'blah3'
   ...

   androidTestFlavorCompile 'blah1'
   androidTestFlavorCompile 'blah2'
   androidTestFlavorCompile 'blah3'
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this.

```
configurations {
    [androidTestCompile, androidTestFlavorCompile].each { it.extendsFrom commonCompile }
}

dependencies {
    commonCompile "blah1"    
    commonCompile "blah2"    
    commonCompile "blah3"    
}
```